# Gstreamer rtspsrc proxy mem alloc error

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, http-tunneling

**Hey Guys**

I have one ubuntu machine with gstreamer version 1.8.3 and one arm device with gstreamer version 1.4.4, if I try to use the rtspsrc proxy setting on an gst-launch. I have the same mem allocation error on both devices.

I want to test if is possible to play the axis camera stream over an HTTP tunnel that is described in the axis camera manual as:

> RTSP can be tunnelled over HTTP. This might prove necessary in order
>   to pass firewalls etc. To tunnel RTSP over HTTP, two sessions are set
>   up; one GET (for command replies and stream data) and one POST (for
>   commands). RTSP commands sent on the POST connection are base64
>   encoded, but the replies on the GET connection are in plain text. To
>   bind the two sessions together the Axis product needs a unique ID
>   (conveyed in the x-sessioncookie header). The GET and POST requests
>   are accepted on both the HTTP port (default 80) and the RTSP server
>   port (default 554).

I see at the rtspsrc there is a proxy settings for HTTP tunneling, i dont know if it works, or if I am on the wrong way.

To get forward on this task i would testing this proxy propertie, but if i start the gst-launch I have this mem alloc error.

Pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://root:1qay2wsx@192.168.1.211/axis-media/media.amp" proxy="http://root:1qay2wsx@192.168.1.211/axis-media/media.amp" ! rtph264depay! h264parse ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Error:

```
(gst-launch-1.0:15450): GLib-ERROR **: /build/glib2.0-prJhLS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gmem.c:100: failed to allocate 18446744073709551614 bytes
```

I hope anybody can help me, and thanks for your help guys.

BR Christoph